# How can I define/name a block in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
numbers = 1..10
print numbers.map {|x| x*x}

# I want to do:
square = {|x| x*x}
print numbers.map square
```

Because the syntax is more concise. I there a way to do this without having to use `def` + `end`?

Comment: There are a couple of different ways to creating a block as an object, some of which are deprecated. TIMTOWTDI really applies here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
square = proc {|x| x**2 }
print number.map(&square)
```

Comment: Thanks LBg, what does the & do there?

Comment: `&` transform the Proc object on a block to the method.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot assign a block to a variable because a block isn't really an object per se.

What you *can* do, is assign a `Proc` object to a variable, and then convert that to a block using the `&` unary prefix operator:

```
numbers = 1..10
print numbers.map {|x| x * x }

square = -> x { x * x }
print numbers.map &square
```

Comment: To whomever edited my answer, and the two people who approved that edit: if you have no idea what you're doing, then just don't. I have no problem with people fixing my mistakes, but *introducing* them is not okay. My code works perfectly, yours not only doesn't work, it doesn't even *parse*.

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = 1..10
square = lambda{|x| x*x }
numbers.map &square
```